# How does some websites record screen without user permission?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, webrtc

This website can record our screen without permission https://www.inspectlet.com/hello/capturedemo
but how?

I have tested it on Microsoft Edge, Firefox and Chrome and it works. (All latest versions)

Comment: It is recording the interactions not screen. Try opening browser context menu, it won't show up in final recording. or form auto-suggestions etc. they can record user interaction without permission and create videos based on that.

Comment: ohh I see. Thank you!